# Conditional css based on property bottom value

Tags: css, angular

I have a mat-select-panel that I want to edit the bottom property value like this :

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
    bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

But I want to apply this css only when bottom property is negative.

Is there a easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (it's just an idea):

CSS:

```
::ng-deep .overlay-style-one cdk-overlay-pane {
  bottom: 0px !important;
}

::ng-deep .overlay-style-two cdk-overlay-pane {
  bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select #myselect
      [ngClass]="{ 
         'overlay-style-one': myselect.style.bottom = "100px",
         'overlay-style-two': myselect.style.bottom < 0,
      }"
   >
      <mat-option>-- EXAMPLE --</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="YES">
         Yes
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option value="NO">
          No
      </mat-option>

   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

My doubt is to get the bottom property in that way (#local reference).
If it doesn't work, you alway can use vrender2, or put an id="XXX" to the masSelect, and get the properties in the classic js way:

```
  [ngClass]="{ 
         'overlay-style-one': document.getElementById("XXX").style.bottom < 0,
         'overlay-style-two': document.getElementById("XXX").style.bottom >= 0,
      }"
```